# What does rack mean in AWS EC2 partition placement groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The documentation of AWS [partition placement group](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-partition-placement-groups-for-large-distributed-and-replicated-workloads-in-amazon-ec2/) says:

- Each partition within a placement group has its own set of racks.
- No two partitions within a placement group share the same racks.

[image]

What does rack mean? Are they a shelf of servers that share power and network as a unit? Does it refer to outpost rack?

From [What is an AWS Outpost Rack? - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6OgRawyjIQ):

[image]

### Reference

[Using partition placement groups for large distributed and replicated workloads in Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-partition-placement-groups-for-large-distributed-and-replicated-workloads-in-amazon-ec2/)

Answer (score 0):

It refers to a separate area of the AZ data center with your physical host. The whole point of partitioned placement groups is that hosts are divided between a number of separate physical hosts, that are semi redundant to failing.

Basically they cannot be 2 physical machines sat on the same rack, they need to be seperated.